# How to suppress or redirect to the variable output of the system command

Tags: perl, unit-testing, stderr

I am trying to execute system command for example

```
 system('git clone .....' );
    if ($?) {
        croak('Error while cloning git repository');
    }
```

Here I am checking if result is success, but how not to output the error from the system command, for example in my case, I can get somthing like

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

From executed command.
I need to get this error into the variable and suppress it(don't print this to the terminal)
And than check this error message.
Or at least just supress it.
I need to test such subroutine in the following way

```
dies_ok { MyModule::sub_uses_system_command() } 'Died :(';
```

Is it possible to get such result ?
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) only returns the exit status of the program that was executed, if you want to get the standard output you can use [`qx/command/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) or backticks to execute the command:

```
my $result = `git clone [...] 2>&1`
```

You should note that the `qx/command/` and backticks form of executing commands only returns STDOUT, so if you want to capture STDERR you need to redirect STDERR to STDOUT in your command.

Comment: See also [`Capture::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny) for capturing STDERR separately..

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `system`, use `qx` to capture the output of the command.  It looks like you also want to capture stderr, so use the standard `2>&1` to dup stderr on to stdout.

```
 $var = qx( git clone ... 2>&1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do multiple tests that output to STDERR/STDOUT, you can redirect them within a block and run all those tests within it. Here's a basic example.

```
sub use_system {
    system("asdfasdf asdfasdf");
    croak('this error') if $?;
}

{
    open my $stderr, '>', 'temp.fil' or die $!;
    local *STDERR = $stderr;

    dies_ok { use_system() } 'Died :(';

    # or even

    eval { use_system(); };

    like ($@, qr/this error/, "function failed with 'this error'");
}

warn "STDERR back to normal\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the output:

```
system(`git clone https://example.com/some/path >/dev/null 2>&1`);
```

If the command is built on the fly (needs arguments), `system()` is arguably better than `qx//` because you don't need to involve oneself with interpolation and quoting. You can pass the arguments to the shell and use them in the `-c`'s argument as shell variables:

```
system('sh', '-c', 'echo "$1" "$2" >/dev/null 2>&1', '-', $some, $args)
```